# Delete the parent folder keeping the contained files?

Tags: filesystem

Is it possible that if I have this:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3
/folder1/folder2/file1.txt
```

Can I delete folder2 but keep its content?

So the result would look like:

```
/folder1/folder3
/folder1/file1.txt
```

Answer (score 19):

```
cd /folder1/folder2/
mv * ../
cd ../
```

Now check the contents of the folder:

```
ls
```

Then use this command to delete the directory. It is completely safe since it will *only* delete empty directories:

```
rmdir folder2/
```

Comment: `mv * ..` does not move hidden files.

Comment: correct and that was not the intention of the question. It was about a specific file.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you don't need to actually delete something... just move it away.

```
mv  /folder1/folder2/*  /folder1/
rmdir /folder1/folder2/
```

First command moves the contents to parent directory and the second removed the directory if it's empty. This won't move hidden/dot files. If you want also to move hidden files you would need:

```
mv  /folder1/folder2/{*,.*}  /folder1/
rmdir /folder1/folder2/
```

or use dotglob option in bash. If you don't have dot files it would lead to `no matches found: dir1/dir2/.*` in bash and the command would fail. Also you can ignore the:

```
mv: cannot move ‘folder1/folder2/..’ to ‘folder1/..’: Device or resource busy
```

errors since bash passes `.` and `..` to `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

To also handle hidden files:

`mv $(find folder2 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1) . && rmdir folder2`

If it exceeds `ARG_MAX`, use this one instead:

`find folder2 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} . \; && rmdir folder2`

Rinzwind's answer does not handle hidden files. If you are using `bash` and want to match all hidden files by `*` wildcard, you would need `shopt -s dotglob` at first or just put it in `~/.bashrc`.

demo:

```
$ find .
.
./folder2
./folder2/.hidden
./folder2/file1.txt
./folder2/folder3

$ mv $(find folder2 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1) . && rmdir folder2

$ find .
.
./.hidden
./file1.txt
./folder3
```